# Multiple Token lifetimes in WebAPI2 with asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I am using the asp.net Identity provider with the OWIN middleware with OAuth in my WebAPI application. Using the template and the

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples

I have working OAuth on my WebAPI endpoints. However, I am failing to see how to extend this architecture to provide different Token lifetimes for different requests.

For example, my REST API will be consumed by a web app, and a mobile app. I want the mobile app to have a much longer token lifetime than the web application.

In my Startup.Auth.cs file I see the following OAuth configuration-

```
        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider<ApplicationUserManager, DirectoryUser, Guid>(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        });
```

Is there a way to override this behavior per token request? For example I could expose a 
"/Token" -> 14 days and a "/DeviceToken" -> 60 days. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to fix this my inserting the following into my OAuth provider (ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs) from the sample-

```
   public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.Get<TUserManager>();

        TUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);


        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }


        //if user, expire 60. If Admin, 14 days
        if (userManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Users"))
        {
            context.Options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(60);
        }
        else {
            context.Options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);


        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with the answer. I will be doing something similar in the near future and your question answer will come in very handy.

Comment: No problem, I will keep it open for a day or so in case someone has a better solution, then I will mark it answered

Comment: `context.Options` is a reference to `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` in your `OAuth configuration`. So, when you change an options in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` that mean you change `AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan` globally.  So I prefer dichen's answers as the best answers.

Answer (score 1):

Setting context.Options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan will actually change the global value, and affect all requests, that won't work for the original requirement.

The right place is the TokenEndpoint method.

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    ...

    if (isRequestFromDevice)
    {
        context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(60);
    }

    ...
}
```